# Why does running Netflix not cause a bump in video decode?

Tags: firefox, codec, video-codecs, netflix

I don't have any performance issues - just curious about the internals of web browsers.

My understanding is Netflix uses H.264, VP9, or against some devices AV1. I wasn't able to figure out which codec was in use in my case - not sure if there is a way to tell? I was doing my testing in Firefox.

I took a look at the performance tab and task manager and video decode stays completely flat:

[image]

I see some minor activity (highlighted) when I refresh the page, but that's it. The GPU is a 3080 Ti so I wouldn't have expected to see much, but I did expect the result to be non-zero.

Why is that? Does the CPU do all of it? Even the CPU usage remains extremely low but perhaps the demands are just... well, low. It's playing on a 4k monitor if that changes anything.

Comment: Check `Compositing` in `about:support` in firefox, and make sure it's showing WebRender, and not Software or anything. It's common to see usage in 3D if you're missing some codec, or the browser doesn't like your drivers too. Try checking if Edge or Chrome behave the same way? I found someone who got firefox to use Decode (for youtube) by installing the K lite mega codec pack, but hard to know for sure

Comment: Also, netflix bitrate is tiny unless you have premium plan. Check out youtube 4k60fps videos to get a noticeable usage increase of some kind, though codec might be different